# My batch script doesn't work. Can anyone tell me why?

Tags: debugging, command-prompt, batch-file

I need help with my script. All of the stuff keeps falling through and not doing the goto. Can you help?

```
@ECHO OFF
goto joshua
:joshua
Echo Hello my name is Joshua.
echo What is yours?
set /p name=
cls
Echo Hello %name%.
cls
Echo How are you?
set /p feeling=
cls
echo Is this good?
echo Im sorry I am still learning human feelings.
set /p humanfeelings=Yes/No
if %humanfeelings%==Yes goto Good
if %humanfeelings%==No goto Bad
cls
:Good
Echo Well that is pleasent.
Echo Would you like to play a game %name%?
set /p answer=Yes/No
if %answer%==Yes goto startmenu
if %answer%== No goto quit
cls
:Bad
echo That is not good.
echo Would you like to play a game %name%?
set /p answera=Yes/No
if %answera%==Yes goto startmenu
if %answera%== No goto later
cls
:startmenu
start menu.bat
cls
:later
Echo That is fine %name%, maybe later
pause
exit
```

Comment: I see a big wall of unformatted code. Please do fix your post. Atleast provide the newlines.

Comment: ok sorry
i didn't relize

Comment: Delete the code from your current post. Press the code button on the formatting toolbar, the one that looks like: `{ }`. Then copy-paste your original code.

Comment: why did it do that agian

Comment: thanks sorry this is the first time i have used this site so do you see any problems in the scripting?

Comment: Could you clarify to which goto doesn't it go?.. What's the expected/real output?

Comment: Can you please say exactly what you input, exactly what you expect to happen, and what really happens? I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code.

Comment: Ok what happens is it goes through all the gotos no matter the answer and i expect it if you put in an answer to go to a specific one not all of them did that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Your original code with line numbers:

```
1 :  @ECHO OFF
2 :  goto joshua
3 :  :joshua
4 :  Echo Hello my name is Joshua.
5 :  echo What is yours?
6 :  set /p name=
7 :  cls
8 :  Echo Hello %name%.
9 :  cls
10:  Echo How are you?
11:  set /p feeling=
12:  cls
13:  echo Is this good?
14:  echo Im sorry I am still learning human feelings.
15:  set /p humanfeelings=Yes/No
16:  if %humanfeelings%==Yes goto Good
17:  if %humanfeelings%==No goto Bad
18:  cls
19:  :Good
20:  Echo Well that is pleasent.
21:  Echo Would you like to play a game %name%?
22:  set /p answer=Yes/No
23:  if %answer%==Yes goto startmenu
24:  if %answer%== No goto quit
25:  cls
26:  :Bad
27:  echo That is not good.
28:  echo Would you like to play a game %name%?
29:  set /p answera=Yes/No
30:  if %answera%==Yes goto startmenu
31:  if %answera%== No goto later
32:  cls
33:  :startmenu
34:  start menu.bat
35:  cls
36:  :later
37:  Echo That is fine %name%, maybe later
38:  pause
39:  exit
```

- Line 2: `goto joshua` unnecessary since joshua is at the very next line.
- Line 9: `cls` erases the preceding echo (hides `Hello %name%.`)
- Line 16, 17, 30, and 31: variables should be quoted or else unexpected input (e.g., `hell
  no!!!` or `yes, i am.`) would cause a syntax error
- Line 18, 25, and 32: there is no default case, so if the answer is neither "Yes" nor "No", the script continues to the next line.

I'd also suggest changing these if statements into if-else, and use case-insensitive string comparison with `if /I`. Try these modifications:

```
@echo off

:joshua
echo Hello. My name is Joshua.
echo What is yours?
set /p name=
cls
echo Hello, %name%.
echo How are you?
set /p feeling=
cls

echo Is this good?
echo I'm sorry. I am still learning human feelings.
set /p humanfeelings=Yes/No 

if /I "%humanfeelings%"=="yes" (
    goto Good
) else (
    goto Bad
) 
cls

:Good
echo Well that is pleasant.
goto AskPlay

:Bad
echo That is not good.

:AskPlay
echo Would you like to play a game, %name%?
set /p answera=Yes/No
if /I "%answera%"=="yes" (
    goto startmenu
) else (
    goto later
)
cls

:startmenu
start menu.bat
cls

:later
echo That is fine, %name%. Maybe later!
pause
exit
```

Comment: @ME1: line numbers removed. enjoy

Answer (score 1):

Okay, from what I see wrong here is that you don't jump anywhere in the end of Good/Bad handling. This means that no matter if you type "Yes" or "No", Bad/startmenu/later blocks are always executed, one after another. Is that the problem you're having? Then just add some more goto-s.

Comment: yes it is and what is a "goto-s" sorry i haven't done this in a long time and im not up to date on all the commands

Comment: "Goto-s" are "goto" statements, like the one on 2nd line of your example. So they are instruction modifying script execution flow.

Comment: ok so add more of the things like goto joshua (without a variable)

Comment: If someone could possible rewrite it if you see an issue becuase i honestly don't know waht you are all talking about thank you

Comment: Commands in batch file are executed line by line, one after another. When you use `goto` command, you alter that behavior by telling interpreter which line to execute next (by specifying label name with this `goto` statement; labels are those lines starting with colon). Labels themselves don't do anything and if interpreter reads line containing label it just skips it. As an example, for code to work as you expect, you might need to add `:end` label as a last line in your script and add `goto end` before `:Good`, `:Bad` and `:startmenu` lines.

Comment: One `:end` line at the end of script. You really need to get an idea of this `goto` statement. Try reading output of `help goto` command executed in command line.

Comment: I wonder if it's really you who wrote the script (taking in account there already are some `goto` statements and you don't understand how they work). Maybe some other reading (like [this one](http://commandwindows.com/batchfiles-branching.htm)) could help.

Comment: see now that was uncalled for i understood that they would cuase it to goto somewhere else i did write this all on my own and i am sorry if you are just a confusing person

Answer (score 0):

Are you typing the full answer Yes or No in response to the prompts?  If you abbreviate to Y and N, only those initial characters will get stored.

Comment: yes im using Yes and No with captails just as i wrote them in the set

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the space before the word `No` in these lines:

```
if %answer%== No goto quit
```

and

```
if %answera%== No goto later
```

Like many of us who have outlived our usefulness, the batch interpreter is old and fussy. :-)

Comment: it helped a little but i think there are more flaws in my script but thank you very much

Comment: The spaces works before and after the No, the batch interpreter is old but not senile :-)

Comment: @jeb, actually, the space here matters. the batch interpreter will compare `answera` to " No" (which does not match "No"). try it out.

Comment: @bstn, I tried it and it works. This gives true: IF    NO  ==NO (echo true) ELSE (echo false)

Comment: @jeb, you're right. my bad. i'm not sure why i thought it didn't work. perhaps i accidentally used lowercase "no" when testing for failure and the correct case " No" when testing for success.